# XAML with MultiDataTrigger and NullToBoolConverter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, triggers

I try to get a Button to Enable if all textbox have a value but it doesn´t work and i can´t find out why.

NullToBoolConverter.cs

```
public class NullToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(bool));
        bool nullResult = false;
        if (parameter != null)
            nullResult = (bool)converter.ConvertFrom(parameter);
        if (value == null)
            return nullResult;
        else
            return !nullResult;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

XAML-Ressourcedict.

```
<ex:NullToBoolConverter x:Key="NullToBoolConverter"/>

<Style x:Key="okButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Hostadress, Converter={StaticResource NullToBoolConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding UserBox, Converter={StaticResource NullToBoolConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True"  />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding PasswordTextBox, Converter={StaticResource NullToBoolConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding PortBox, Converter={StaticResource NullToBoolConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and I your only problem is that you are only comparing the value to `null` and not to `string.Empty`. Try this

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(bool));
    bool nullResult = false;
    if (parameter != null)
        nullResult = (bool)converter.ConvertFrom(parameter);
    if (value == null || value.ToString() == string.Empty)
        return nullResult;
    else
        return !nullResult;
}
```

Comment: I use `<Button Content="OK" Style="{DynamicResource okButtonStyle}"/>` with your converter but nothing happens, i still have a disabled control. I also have set breakpoints to the converter but never staop there..

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is the `DataContext` for `Button`. Compare it to my sample, uploaded it here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39657172/BindingTest.zip

Comment: The problem is the Binding in the DataTriggers. My code below works.

Comment: @Eclipsed4utoo: The `Style` is applied on a `Button` so the Bindings in the DataTriggers will use the same `DataContext` as the `Button`. So it all comes down to how it's meant to be used.

Answer (score 2):

I changed your converter to this, as it just seemed to be a lot simpler...

```
public class NullToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return false;

        string currentValue = value.ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentValue))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Then your XAML style should look like this...

```
    <ex:NullToBoolConverter
        x:Key="NullToBoolConverter" />

    <Style
        x:Key="okButtonStyle"
        TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter
            Property="IsEnabled"
            Value="False" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        Binding="{Binding ElementName=Hostadress, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource NullToBoolConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Value="True" />
                    <Condition
                        Binding="{Binding ElementName=UserBox, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource NullToBoolConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Value="True" />
                    <Condition
                        Binding="{Binding ElementName=PasswordTextBox, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource NullToBoolConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Value="True" />
                    <Condition
                        Binding="{Binding ElementName=PortBox, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource NullToBoolConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter
                    Property="IsEnabled"
                    Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Debugging worked and typing in all of the textboxes would enable the button.

Notice that I changed the Binding statements to use the ElementName and Path.

Comment: I'm just wondering.  You marked Meleak's post as the answer, yet stated in the comments that it didn't work.  So how exactly is it the answer if it didn't fix your problem?  Just wondering.

Comment: he have uploaded his demo-project, found out that i have to set my datacontext ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I simplified a little bit code:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(bool))]
public class NullToBoolValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var result = value == null;
        return parameter != null ? !result : result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Further simplifying:
`public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
 return !(parameter == null ^ value == null);
}`